# .htaccess subdomain directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L]

Rewritecomnd %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
Rewritecomnd %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /profile/index.php?name=%1 [L]

Rewritecomnd %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
Rewritecomnd %{HTTP_HOST} [^.]+\.example\.com [NC]
Rewritecomnd %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule !^profile/ /profile/%1 [L]
```

let me tell you what this does:

1. `bob.example.com` shows page `www.example.com/profile/index.php?name=bob`
2. `bob.example.com/page1.php` shows page from only **profile** directory `www.example.com/profile/page1.php`

**Question:**

The problem is, if I go to `bob.example.com/directory/page.php`, it shows the directory of my root directory. How can I make it so that
`bob.example.com/directory/page.php` shows the `www.example.com/profile/directory/page2.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RewriteCond's pattern does not match the uri **/directory/page.php** . You need to remove the restricted **/** from your regex or use a catch-all pattern instead .

Change your last RewriteCond to this :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
```